# How can I return a vector4 from a pixel shader XNA 4.0

Tags: c#, xna, shader, pixel

I have created two RenderTarget2Ds:

```
currentWorldState = new RenderTarget2D(graphicsDevice, width, height, false, SurfaceFormat.Vector4, DepthFormat.None);
nextWorldState = new RenderTarget2D(graphicsDevice, width, height, false, SurfaceFormat.Vector4, DepthFormat.None);
```

I am trying to write simulation code on the GPU. My goal is to be able to pass vector4 information between these rendertargets. I have created a shader that reads information from the first target, and outputs it to the next target. My problem is that the float4 gets converted into color information and a lot of precision is lost.

This is the header to my pixel shader:

```
float4 CreateActions(in float2 uv : TEXCOORD0) : COLOR
```

Can I change this in any way to ouput the float4 data, changing COLOR to anything else doesn't compile.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the render target format, this is what determines precision :

[Shawn Heargrave](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/archive/2010/07/09/rendertarget-formats-in-xna-game-studio-4-0.aspx) wrote about it and here is the [SurfaceFormat documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.graphics.surfaceformat%28v=xnagamestudio.40%29.aspx)